# Magento 2 - How to create new email template?

Tags: magento2, email-templates

In magento 2, how to create new email template ? 
When users forgot password, or user place new order and then received email.

Comment: Hi please check this link same as for magento 2 http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/customizing-magento-transactional-emails/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Admin panel,

From

> Marketing -> Communication -> Email Templates

Click on Add New Templates,
Get Your required template from Template dropdown at top of page.
Click **Load Template** button.

Now Get Forgot Password from dropdown and click on load template button.

Set Your Template name.

Template Content Textarea are auto fill up.
now you can change text as per your requirement.

```
Save Template.
```

Now you have to set email template for Customer related are

> Stores -> Configuration -> Customer -> Customer Configuration

and all email template for Order Related you can set from

> Stores -> Configuration -> sales -> Sales Email

After set your email template now you can save.
your template are now working for email.